# Solve it using OWASP and ESAPI

Tags: owasp, esapi

Attack Vector: java.io.PrintWriter.write

Description: This call to java.io.PrintWriter.write() contains a cross-site scripting (XSS) flaw. The application populates the HTTP response with user-supplied input, allowing an attacker to embed malicious content, such as Javascript code, which will be executed in the context of the victim's browser. XSS vulnerabilities are commonly exploited to steal or manipulate cookies, modify presentation of content, and compromise confidential information, with new attack vectors being discovered on a regular basis. The first argument to write() contains tainted data. The tainted data originated from an earlier call to javax.servlet.servletrequest.getparameter. The tainted data is directed into an output stream returned by org.apache.jasper.runtime.pagecontextimpl.getout.

It is in the code  first argument of writer.write(arg1) .. pls help me regarding this

Answer (score 1):

I think this refers to the fact that you can use a user's input that is not sanitized.

For example in the below simplified servlet a user can print his/her own name by passing in a parameter.

http://xxx/servlet/vulnerable?someuserinput=Bob

But suppose an attacker sent out a link via email with something nasty in the link.

http://xxx/servlet/vulnerable?someuserinput=alert("Hello! I am doing something nasty!!");

The rule of thumb is always sanitize your inputs

```
@WebServlet(name = "vulnerable", urlPatterns = {"/vulnerable"})
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String someUserInput = request.getParameter("someuserinput");

        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

            out.write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.write("<html>");
            out.write("<head>");       
            out.write("</head>");
            out.write("<body>");
            out.write("<h1>Hello " + someUserInput + "</h1>");//something bad can happen here 
            out.write("</body>");
            out.write("</html>");
        }
    }
```

I know you are asking about ESAPI, but OWASP has HTML simple Sanitizer.

https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer

ESAPI in the context of HTML (Like above)

```
String safer = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML( request.getParameter( "someuserinput" ) );
```

ESAPI in the context of Javascript

```
String safer = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForJavaScript( request.getParameter( "someuserinput" ) );
```

Comment: That will work... if the context is HTML.  If the parameter is going to be used by a javascript framework, say AngularJS or just plain old javascript, then you'd want to use `encodeForJavaScript()`

Comment: And semantically... don't use the word "safe" when dealing with user input.  You don't want people to lose vigilance with their code.

Comment: Yeah . Thanks ! But if i want to encode Writer.write(somearg) then which encoding should i use to prevent the cross site scripting ..

Comment: I encode the following using  writer.write(encoder.encodeForHTMLAttribute(output.toString()));                             Is this correct . ?

Comment: @Kunal Ganatra , I think it depends on where you are using the output. It will depend on your use case. So if you are using the value to find an attribute , then yes. encodeForHTML will work well for the example I provided.